# Determining if an over constrained system of linear inequalities has a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry

I have a system of inequalities of the form:

$$ X \cdot v_i \leq 0 $$

For some number of vectors $v_i$.

I need to determine if there exists at least one $X$ that can satisfy all of them at once (I don't need to find $X$ I just need to know if it exists).

I need to be able to do this computationally, so graphing the solution won't really work.

$X$ is a vector of the same dimension as $v_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Can't you just feed the system to a linear solver and check if the solver finds a solution or not ?

Comment: Is $X$ a vector? a number? a matrix? Has fixed dimensions?

Comment: @Kuifje This is an over constrained system of inequalities, there may be no solution to the equality while there being a solution to the inequalities. Moreover there's always the trivial solution of $X=0$ but that isn;t ssuper useful to me.

Comment: @Exodd I edited the questio, yes $x$ has fixed dimension.

Comment: Weeelll... $X=0$ is always a solution...

Comment: @Exodd I did say that in my coment, as mentioned Ineed to know if there are more answer than the trivial one.

Comment: You should explicitely mention this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\matrix(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^+\times ... \times \mathbb{R}^+$ denote your variables and $V=\matrix(v_1,...,v_n)$ denote the parameters.

You want to know if the following system has a solution:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_iv_i &\le 0 \tag{1}\\
\end{align}

You can feed this to any linear solver (see for example [PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/)) with a dummy objective function (e.g. $0$), and the solver will either find a solution, or tell you that the system is not feasible. So calling the solver will give you your certificate.

If your variables are not restricted to non negative values, perform the change of variables ($x_i=x_i'-x_i{''}$) to have this restriction, as explained for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455611/why-do-the-decision-variables-in-a-linear-optimization-problem-have-to-be-non-ne).

If you want at least one non negative element, then add the constraint
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge \epsilon
$$
where $\epsilon$ is your tolerance value.

Comment: $x_i$ is absolutely not a constraint, only $x_i \neq 0$ negative values are not just allowed but sometimes necessary.

Comment: So you need at least one non zero element $x_i$?

Comment: yes that's correct.

Comment: In this case I believe my proposed solution is satisfactory.